# Using JavaScript or html to pull live data(cryptocurrency statistics from another site)

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a beginner to coding and I'm creating a site on educating teens on cryptocurrency where I would like to have a page consisting of live data of different currencies using only javascript and html(css if needed to). Seen a lot on fetch api, etc, but really not sure on how to do it.

Comment: I think you mean JavaScript, not Java...

Answer (score 0):

You want to look for Jquery library for JS, HTML and CSS will not be enough to do api calls, JS will do that for you,

Having timer set to x amount to call the api and feed the html with data.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, to fetch data from a website, you can use the Fetch API.

This is an example that fetches data from [this GitHub page](https://api.github.com/zen).

```js
fetch('https://api.github.com/zen')
.then(resp => resp.text())
.then(text => console.log(text));
```

If the response is in JSON, you can use `resp.json()` instead of `resp.text()` to parse it into a JavaScript object.

Comment: This code doesn't work for me. I am using brackets and just testing on live preview. Do I need a domain for fetch tag to work? The fetch is white colour on my code by the way.